# Does SHOWPLAN permission allow users to view plans by other users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As the title says, I am trying to figure out if the SHOWPLAN database level permission will grant an user permission to view plans and queries by other users in the database?

I am little confused from what I have read in the Microsoft documentation. Would appreciate any insight on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `SHOWPLAN` permission enables a user to view the execution plan for their own queries.

To view plans and queries from other users (IE view the plan cache via `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`) they will need `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission which is a different permission entirely

[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: SHOWPLAN enables the use of "set showplan" commands for their own queries, is that correct?